# date-fns: how to to get the current date + time in format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss:dddddd

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-fns

My company is using date-fns and I'm trying to set a variable equal to the current date + time. We must use date-fns, and the format is specified to be 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.dddddd'.

How can I do this? I tried simply `format(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss:dddddd')`, but that was not working as expected.

(Also what is the 'T' for? Just to specify that a time measurement will follow? And what are the d's?)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern is not correct e.g. you need

1. `y` instead of `Y`
2. `d` instead of `D`
3. `H` instead of `h`

etc. Check [this page](https://date-fns.org/v2.23.0/docs/format) to learn more about these letters.

**Demo:**

```
const fns = require('date-fns')

console.log(fns.format(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
2021-08-03T19:43:08.891
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-fns-playground-kgvsui)

(**Note:** Click `Console` on the bottom right of the ONLINE DEMO page.)

> (Also what is the 'T' for? Just to specify that a time measurement
> will follow?

Correct. It is a separator for date and time as per [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed. I also added the single quotes around the T which made it much easier to read.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you run/test the above code? Did you just create a file in your editor, add the two lines of code, and run it? (I don't even know what the compile/run command is for .js files, geez)

Comment: @tprebenda - You are most welcome. You need to install nodejs first and then you need to install the date-fns npm module. Check https://nodejs.org/en/ and https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns